# Adding a scrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a scrollview and its initialize as this ;

```
scrollV = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
```

Later in the application i add a UIView, and i need the UIView to take the height and width of the scrollView. (Since a scrollView can very in its length i can't hard code the value)

So i tried this ;

```
justAnotherView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.scrollV.frame.size.width, self.scrollV.frame.size.height)];
```

But, it isn't taking the size of the scrollview (the total size of the scrollview). It only shows part of the screen (width 320 and height 460). Is this because of the `scrollV` initialization statement i wrote above ? How can i correct this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use the `contentSize` property of the UIScrollView instead.

```
... initWithFrame:CGMakeRect(0,0,scrollV.contentSize.width, scrollV.contentSize.height) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
justAnotherView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.scrollV.frame];
```

Comment: Shouldn't `CGRectMake(0, 0, self.scrollV.frame.size.width, self.scrollV.frame.size.height)` and `self.scrollV.frame` be the same ?

Comment: Not at all. X and Y aren't the same as scrollV's.

Comment: Actually, if he added justAnotherView as a subview to scrollV, then this would not work as justAnotherView's x and y are relative to its parent.  If justAnotherView was, indeed, added as a subview, then Illep has done the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you added `justAnotherView` as a subview to `scrollV`:

Just as you did for `justAnotherView`, you should set `scrollV`'s point and size relative to its parent.   It should look something like this:

```
scrollV = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,parent.frame.size.width,parent.frame.size.height)];
```